# Copy data with Full Load Without changing destination

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Hello please I need your help,

I have pipline with copy activity to load the data from an excel file to my datalake, each time the pipline run I need to get all the data from the source. another thing I need to add new column that has the year of the day when the pipline run.

Another thing, when I run the pipeline, it works fine for the first time and the data is copied to the destination. However, when I run the pipeline again, even if I have added new rows to my source, nothing is changing in the destination. I thought that when I rerun the pipeline, I would get all the data from the source appended to the data that is already in the destination that's what I need to do.
[image]

Thank you alot in advance.